# Remove extension in file uploading in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to upload my files with an encrypted name with CodeIgniter.
But, I try the 2 possibilities :

```
$config['file_name'] = md5($id);
```

Or :

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

Both works, but I have the file extension in my encripted name. Is it possible to remove it when uploading my file ?
When I see the Upload system library, the $file->ext is used everywhere.. Why put the file extension in an encrypted name ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There really is a much easier way of doing this:

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload())  // If file was uploaded
{           
    $data = $this->upload->data(); // Returns information about your uploaded file.
    $new_name=md5($id);
    $thumbnail = $new_name.$data['file_ext']; // Here it is
}
```

Comment: I want to remove extension in do_upload() function. I know how to retrieve it, but I want to have an uploaded file with an encrypted name, without extension.

Comment: i think that you have to upload without upload helper
i mean u have to upload with pure upload

Comment: I think the same.. I just can't understand why CodeIgniter put the extension in an encrypted filename.

Comment: you can create new upload helper and create new functions remove extension if you want i can create it for you

Answer (score 0):

Open `system/libraries/Upload.php`

Remove or Comment out this code from `do_upload` function

```
// If no extension was provided in the file_name config item, use the uploaded one
if (strpos($this->_file_name_override, '.') === FALSE)
{
  $this->file_name .= $this->file_ext;
}
else
{
  // An extension was provided, let's have it!
  $this->file_ext = $this->get_extension($this->_file_name_override);
}
```